# Firefox Marketplace listing app icon not saving

Tags: firefox, web-applications, marketplace

Has anyone had this problem? 
I am submitting an app to the Firefox Marketplace and I am not able to add an app icon. Under edit listing -> media -> edit -> app icon, I can add an icon successfully, but after saving changes the App Icon still is not uploaded.
Link to pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImrVt.jpg